# Javascript : functions without prototype

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

**Built-in functions** in javascript (e.g. `Object.keys`) don't have a "prototype" property.

```
Object.keys.prototype === undefined;             // returns true
Array.prototype.slice.prototype === undefined;   // returns true
```

However, either `function(){...}` or `new Function()` will generate a constructor (instance of Function) along with a prototype (instance of Object). Isn't it too expensive?

Is is possible to create **a pure function** instead of a **constructor** in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

The question is "what does 'creating' them mean"?

For all intent and purpose,

```
function myFunc ( ) { }

myFunc.constructor = undefined;
myFunc.prototype = undefined;
```

will get you what you want, from a practical standpoint.

In ES6, lambdas should have no ties to other functions;

```
(() => { }).prototype === undefined; // I believe this should be 100% true
```

...your other question...  ...is it too expensive that there are added functions/objects created for each function...

....well, there are games running happily on browsers. Talking about the memory consumption from making functions is typically immeasurably small, these days (though IoT / wearables would be a concern).
That's a premature micro-optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `Math.random`, built-in functions in JS are pure by design. You shouldn't derive a function with `new` statement which it won't do the right job for you.

JavaScript is a multi-paradigm programming language which exposes both `functional` and `oop` senses. So, you have pure functions without prototype:

```
Math.round // whose typeof is function
Math.floor // whose typeof is also function
```

Above, `Math` could be perceived as a namespace instead of an Object type. So it is just a container which supplies a set of functions for you.

In contrast, if you refer to **functions of prototype objects** in JavaScript, you will get an undefined unless you refer to them via prototype:

```
Array.map // undefined
Array.reduce // undefined
```

This is because of the matter fact that **Array is not designed to be a namespace like Math, it is a class of object in OOP sense.** So you need to call the function via its instance like:

```
var list = new Array(3);
list.map(function(a){ return 1 });
```

Otherwise, you may refer to the function via `prototype` to gain access to the pure function where `this` object is not bound. See following statement:

```
var list = [1,2,3];
typeof(Array.prototype.map); // It's pure, unbound
Array.prototype.map.call( list, function(a){ return a*2 }); // Usage in a purely-functional way
```

The meaning behind this is, JavaScript is designed to be writable in both OOP and Functional ways. You may need to play around with function prototype as I have given you some examples above and this will clarify you further :)